# Can't access global variable from other files in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, variables, global

I'm trying to access my config.js file in all modules of my project but I can't even though the config file is defined as global.

Here's my packaging:

[image]

in the server.js I have defined:

```
global.config = require('./app/config');
```

I can access the properties of config in server.js but when I try to use `config` in other files such as user.js I get this error:

```
config is not defined
```

I don't know how to fix the way I'm defining this global variable.

Comment: Why not use [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't make any sense but when I moved the global variable above the variable which contained the router it worked.

```
global.config = require("./app/config");
const routeHandler = require('./app/routes/index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `config.js` file isn't imported into the runtime of the program that you start. Make sure you import `config.js` at least once into your runtime